# loading ELF file in C in user space

Tags: linux, assembly, loader, elf

I am trying to load an ELF file compiled with "gcc -m32 test.c -o test.exe" on Linux in a 64 bit x86 environment. I am trying to load that 32bit file (test.exe) inside a user space ELF loader which has the following core logic (32bit ELF).

The problem is that calling into the returned start address results in
a segmentation fault core dump. Here is the code:

```c
void *image_load (char *elf_start, unsigned int size)
{
    Elf32_Ehdr      *hdr    = NULL;
    Elf32_Phdr      *phdr   = NULL;
    unsigned char   *start  = NULL;
    Elf32_Addr      taddr   = 0;
    Elf32_Addr      offset  = 0;
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char *exec = NULL;
    Elf32_Addr      estart = 0;

    hdr = (Elf32_Ehdr *) elf_start;

    if(!is_image_valid(hdr)) {
        printk("image_load:: invalid ELF image\n");
        return 0;
    }

    exec = (unsigned char *)mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                      MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);

    if(!exec) {
        printk("image_load:: error allocating memory\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Start with clean memory.
    memset(exec,0x0,size);

    phdr = (Elf32_Phdr *)(elf_start + hdr->e_phoff);

    for(i=0; i < hdr->e_phnum; ++i) {
            if(phdr[i].p_type != PT_LOAD) {
                    continue;
            }
            if(phdr[i].p_filesz > phdr[i].p_memsz) {
                    printk("image_load:: p_filesz > p_memsz\n");
                    munmap(exec, size);
                    return 0;
            }
            if(!phdr[i].p_filesz) {
                    continue;
            }

            // p_filesz can be smaller than p_memsz,
            // the difference is zeroe'd out.
            start = (unsigned char *) (elf_start + phdr[i].p_offset);
            // taddr = phdr[i].p_vaddr + (Elf32_Addr)exec;
            if(!estart) {
                estart = phdr[i].p_paddr;
            }
            taddr = (Elf32_Addr)exec + offset + (phdr[i].p_paddr - estart);
            memmove((unsigned char *)taddr,
                    (unsigned char *)start,phdr[i].p_filesz);
            offset += (phdr[i].p_memsz + (phdr[i].p_paddr - estart));

            if(!(phdr[i].p_flags & PF_W)) {
                    // Read-only.
                    mprotect((unsigned char *) taddr, 
                              phdr[i].p_memsz,
                              PROT_READ);
            }

            if(phdr[i].p_flags & PF_X) {
                    // Executable.
                    mprotect((unsigned char *) taddr, 
                            phdr[i].p_memsz,
                            PROT_EXEC);
            }
    }

    return (void *)((hdr->e_entry - estart) + (Elf32_Addr)exec);

}/* image_load */

...
    int (*main)(int, char **)=image_load(...);
    main(argc,argv); // Crash...
...
```

Comment: `printk` suggests a kernel module, while `mmap` & `mprotect` are user-space. If you are coding a user-space application, did you consider compiling it with `gcc -Wall -g` and debugging it with `gdb` ? And the start address of an ELF image is *not* the `main` routine (but some `_start` in some `crt0.o`)

Answer (score 31):

Please provide full runnable code, including the ELF that you are trying to load.
I have taken the time to amend your code as best I could, and it seems to work, at least for this simple code.

Note that the loader must also be compiled as 32 bit code, you can not load a 32 bit file into a 64 bit process. Furthermore since you are not loading the code in the original place, it must be relocatable. Finally, it must be a static binary because you are not loading any libraries.

**Update**: Your code expects the entry point of the loaded code to conform to the `int (*main)(int, char **)` prototype which is not the case in general (side note: `main` actually gets a third argument, the environment, too). Read about the [startup state of ELF](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html). If you manually create the stack layout described there, you must jump to the entry point, and that will never return. In case of a C program, you could dig out the address of `main` and that would match the prototype. However you are then skipping the initalization of the C library (remember, your code doesn't do library loading, so the loaded program must be statically linked) and that could be a problem.

I have extended the code with the needed bits to handle a simple C program by resolving libc references and invoking `main`.

*loader.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libelf.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

void printk(const char* msg)
{
    fputs(msg, stderr);
}

int is_image_valid(Elf32_Ehdr *hdr)
{
    return 1;
}

void *resolve(const char* sym)
{
    static void *handle = NULL;
    if (handle == NULL) {
        handle = dlopen("libc.so", RTLD_NOW);
    }
    return dlsym(handle, sym);
}

void relocate(Elf32_Shdr* shdr, const Elf32_Sym* syms, const char* strings, const char* src, char* dst)
{
    Elf32_Rel* rel = (Elf32_Rel*)(src + shdr->sh_offset);
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < shdr->sh_size / sizeof(Elf32_Rel); j += 1) {
        const char* sym = strings + syms[ELF32_R_SYM(rel[j].r_info)].st_name;
        switch(ELF32_R_TYPE(rel[j].r_info)) {
            case R_386_JMP_SLOT:
            case R_386_GLOB_DAT:
                *(Elf32_Word*)(dst + rel[j].r_offset) = (Elf32_Word)resolve(sym);
                break;
        }
    }
}

void* find_sym(const char* name, Elf32_Shdr* shdr, const char* strings, const char* src, char* dst)
{
    Elf32_Sym* syms = (Elf32_Sym*)(src + shdr->sh_offset);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < shdr->sh_size / sizeof(Elf32_Sym); i += 1) {
        if (strcmp(name, strings + syms[i].st_name) == 0) {
            return dst + syms[i].st_value;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *image_load (char *elf_start, unsigned int size)
{
    Elf32_Ehdr      *hdr     = NULL;
    Elf32_Phdr      *phdr    = NULL;
    Elf32_Shdr      *shdr    = NULL;
    Elf32_Sym       *syms    = NULL;
    char            *strings = NULL;
    char            *start   = NULL;
    char            *taddr   = NULL;
    void            *entry   = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    char *exec = NULL;

    hdr = (Elf32_Ehdr *) elf_start;

    if(!is_image_valid(hdr)) {
        printk("image_load:: invalid ELF image\n");
        return 0;
    }

    exec = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                      MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);

    if(!exec) {
        printk("image_load:: error allocating memory\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Start with clean memory.
    memset(exec,0x0,size);

    phdr = (Elf32_Phdr *)(elf_start + hdr->e_phoff);

    for(i=0; i < hdr->e_phnum; ++i) {
            if(phdr[i].p_type != PT_LOAD) {
                    continue;
            }
            if(phdr[i].p_filesz > phdr[i].p_memsz) {
                    printk("image_load:: p_filesz > p_memsz\n");
                    munmap(exec, size);
                    return 0;
            }
            if(!phdr[i].p_filesz) {
                    continue;
            }

            // p_filesz can be smaller than p_memsz,
            // the difference is zeroe'd out.
            start = elf_start + phdr[i].p_offset;
            taddr = phdr[i].p_vaddr + exec;
            memmove(taddr,start,phdr[i].p_filesz);

            if(!(phdr[i].p_flags & PF_W)) {
                    // Read-only.
                    mprotect((unsigned char *) taddr,
                              phdr[i].p_memsz,
                              PROT_READ);
            }

            if(phdr[i].p_flags & PF_X) {
                    // Executable.
                    mprotect((unsigned char *) taddr,
                            phdr[i].p_memsz,
                            PROT_EXEC);
            }
    }

    shdr = (Elf32_Shdr *)(elf_start + hdr->e_shoff);

    for(i=0; i < hdr->e_shnum; ++i) {
        if (shdr[i].sh_type == SHT_DYNSYM) {
            syms = (Elf32_Sym*)(elf_start + shdr[i].sh_offset);
            strings = elf_start + shdr[shdr[i].sh_link].sh_offset;
            entry = find_sym("main", shdr + i, strings, elf_start, exec);
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i < hdr->e_shnum; ++i) {
        if (shdr[i].sh_type == SHT_REL) {
            relocate(shdr + i, syms, strings, elf_start, exec);
        }
    }

   return entry;

}/* image_load */

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)
{
    int (*ptr)(int, char **, char**);
    static char buf[1048576];
    FILE* elf = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    fread(buf, sizeof buf, 1, elf);
    ptr=image_load(buf, sizeof buf);
    return ptr(argc,argv,envp);
}
```

*elf.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello world! fprintf=%p, stdout=%p\n", fprintf, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

---

test run:

```
$ gcc -m32 -g -Wall -ldl -o loader loader.c
$ gcc -m32 -pie -fPIE -o elf elf.c
$ ./loader elf
Hello world! fprintf=0xf7612420, stdout=0xf770e4c0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem appears to be when you try to load a C program (even a simple one that prints hello world). My guess is that either there is a problem calling the C _start routine directly, or that the loader code has a bug relocating more than one section (around where the call to memmove is made).

Comment: sorry for this, but I just wanted to know where you guys get the libelf libraries. Thank you

Comment: this is a very old thread, but, do you not need to worry about things being page aligned in your code?

Comment: @user1018513 here we are loading a proper ELF binary created by the normal toolchain, so all the alignment is already taken care of.

Comment: This isn't a very efficient way of doing things. That buffer is just for reading in the whole file. You can simply [stat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) it to get the size.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the size of the `mmap`. Would it be the value of adding all `p_memsz` together? Also, if I'm just trying to load in my own shared library that does not link to anything else and no `libc` do I need to do relocation?

Answer (score 7):

> exec = (unsigned char *)mmap(NULL, size, ...

This attempts to load the executable at arbitrary address. A non-PIE executable can only be loaded at the address it was linked at (usually `0x08048000` on Linux/ix86).

> The problem appears to be when you try to load a C program (even a simple one that prints hello world).

If that program was dynamically linked, it is *anything* but simple, and your loader has a *heck of a lot* more to do: loading and relocating dependent shared libraries, fixing up `GOT` and `TLS`, etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
exec = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                  MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, hdr, 0);
```

instead of

```
exec = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                  MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
```