# How does an ELF file determine the offset values of each segment?

Tags: elf, readelf

This is the command I've done:

```
readelf -l helloworld
```

And this is the output:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000002d8 0x00000000000002d8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000318 0x0000000000400318 0x0000000000400318
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000004d0 0x00000000000004d0  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000
                 0x00000000000001d5 0x00000000000001d5  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000402000 0x0000000000402000
                 0x0000000000000148 0x0000000000000148  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002e10 0x0000000000403e10 0x0000000000403e10
                 0x0000000000000214 0x0000000000000218  RW     0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000002e20 0x0000000000403e20 0x0000000000403e20
                 0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d0  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000400338 0x0000000000400338
                 0x0000000000000020 0x0000000000000020  R      0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000358 0x0000000000400358 0x0000000000400358
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_PROPERTY   0x0000000000000338 0x0000000000400338 0x0000000000400338
                 0x0000000000000020 0x0000000000000020  R      0x8
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000002020 0x0000000000402020 0x0000000000402020
                 0x000000000000003c 0x000000000000003c  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000002e10 0x0000000000403e10 0x0000000000403e10
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  R      0x1
```

My question is, where do values like 0x0000000000000318 in the `INTERP` offset come from? And if you can get all the offset information for every segment, how can you get those values exactly if you have all the hex in the elf as a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where do values like 0x0000000000000318 in the INTERP offset come from?

From the program header table, offset to which can be found in the ELF header.

> And if you can get all the offset information for every segment, how can you get those values exactly if you have all the hex in the elf as a vector?

By "hex in the elf as a vector" you *probably* mean "I have the entire contents of the file in memory".

The answer is: you cast the pointer to in-memory data to `Elf32_Ehdr*` or `Elf64_Ehdr*` as appropriate, and go from there.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13915982/50617) has sample code which should get you started.